# Warum heißt es "Tragikomödie" und nicht "Tragikkomödie"?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Das Wort setzt sich ja zusammen aus "Tragik" und "Komödie". Ich sehe nicht, weshalb da ein k wegfallen sollte. Meines Wissens wird das Wort auch mit doppeltem k gesprochen (also so, wie wenn man "Tragik" und "Komödie" ganz normal hintereinander spricht).

Comment: Meine persönliche Volksetymologie ist etwas anders, nämlich eine Zusammensetzung aus Tragödie und Komödie; ähnlich, wie man einen Wissenschaftler, der sich der Physikalischen Chemie widmet, Physikochemiker (und nicht Physikerchemiker) nennt.

Answer (score 7):

Laut [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tragikomoedie) ist die Herkunft lat. tragicomedia. Insofern ist es also wirklich "Tragikomödie" und Tragik'Komödie wäre mithin als Aussprache falsch. Klingt auch sehr holprig.